# Swift hide UIView in a modalPresentationStyle

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` as `modalPresentationStyle` and in there is a `TextView` and a Button(The Button extend a UIView, in which a `SearchBar` is). My problem now is that I try, that the UIView of the `SearchBar` closes when I pressing it again, I have already tried to find a solution, but unfortunately without success.

```
@IBAction func showSearchbar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    let searchbarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    searchbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    textNotiz.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    self.view.addSubview(searchbarView)

    let searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchbarView.frame.width, height: 50))

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
    searchBar.placeholder = " Search..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    searchbarView.addSubview(searchBar)

    if isExpanded == false  {

        isExpanded = true


    } else {

        isExpanded = false
        searchbarView.isHidden = true
        textNotiz.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    }
}
```

**Before Searchbar/View is Expanded**
[image: Before Searchbar/View is Expanded]

**After Searchbar/View is Expanded**
[image: After Searchbar/View is Expanded]

Comment: can you post your screen?

Comment: okay, was added

Comment: It can be because of hiding searchbarView. Or because of not showing it again (if-else statement).

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the problem is that the UIView does not disappear at all. The Text in the UITextView is going up and down, if I press the button, so that works fine, but I don't understand, why the UIView is not hidden than.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I solved the problem, I did not set the variables for the UISearchbar and UIView globally and therefore the UIView did not disappear.